# Is there a term for the psychological issue of "code loss" for programmers?

Tags: programming-languages

I am a programmer. I have just deleted a huge amount of code which I painstakingly researched, thought about, coded, then improved and fixed as bugs popped up for a long time.

All of that code, which took me a ridiculous amount of time, effort and general "mind work", has now been replaced by a very small number of lines which basically leverage PHP's built-in "ICU" features to properly output numbers, money sums and date/time in the correct manner for every combination of language, locale, currency and timezone imaginable.

Previously, I did not know that this already existed, so I basically replicated a lot of it myself, and I now realize how far from perfect it was. But still, I did it, and that code had in my mind "hardened" or "settled" as "gold code" which I never thought I would touch again...

Basically, I mourn my now useless, superseded, obsolete code chunks. I'm annoyed by myself for doing all that unnecessary work and it took a lot of mental wrestling to finally convince myself to go through with it.

Is this common among programmers, and does it have an established term? Such as "code loss" or "code mourning"?

Basically, even though I have really improved my application/library/framework to an extreme degree, it still feels like I've "lost all that work" because the numbers of lines are slashed so much in one go. It's not a nice feeling.

Comment: (Code doesn't die, the thing to mourn here may be life time spent suboptimally.)

Comment: Don’t mourn: relish the opportunities to grow, write hard code, and write beautiful code.

Comment: Our site is for technical questions about computer science.  I'm not sure that this is on-topic here.  Any community votes?

Comment: But just think how much you have gained in experience - (a) by tackling a difficult problem on your own and (b) by learning to say to yourself "maybe someone else has already solved this problem".

Comment: @D.W. I don't see anything here that's specific to programming as opposed to other activities where people might build things and then find out that much of their work was useless. This is a generic psychology question. Maybe a [psychology.se] question?

Comment: @Gilles I think there might be a programming-specific term as well, although it's probably just an instance of the more general phenomenon, and any specific reference would have to be to the Jargon File or something. If it is programming-specific, it might be more on-topic at [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).